# Auto Dash using Javascript on FOCUS (for a telephone number format)

Tags: javascript, regex

Was trying to achieve, an auto dash for this format `XXX-XXX-XXXX`

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('.telnumber').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

First 2 blocks are fine, but How can I restrict the last block to accept 4 digits?

It's still auto dashing if there are 3 digits so far.

I'm not good at REGEX so any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest trying to press e.g. backspace to cancel a mistyped digit before proceeding to destroy UX with this.

Comment: Thanks. But it is forcing an auto dash still.

Comment: Note that with "solutions" like this you can't use the arrow keys to go back and fix an incorrectly typed number. I would consider formatting with hyphens on the blur event, not while typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}$|.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
```

Comment: Nice job! Only one thing: Put the `.{1,4}$` before the `.{1,3}` and it will have priority over it and work correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Here I think best solution. Any non digit chars will be ignored and you will not have extra dashes in the end.

```js
$('.telnumber').keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value
        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
        .replace(/-*$/g, '')
    ;
});
```

Comment: Nice work . one thing is its not allowing to move cursor with left arrow key . Can you please give a solution for it ?

Comment: save prev value and compare it with current value, if it's the same then just `return;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery you might want to check out this jQuery plugin: 
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the regex expression as in the first answer just gave me the below result :
xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx...

This continued.  :(

Hence, I have found a better and perfectly working solution. Simply, add 'maxlength=12' to ur input element!! Checkout the fiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/juspC/218/

```
<input type="text" class="telnumber" maxlength="12" />

$('.telnumber').keyup(function() {
    foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens

        foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}$|.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");

        $(this).val(foo);

    });
```

Comment: Nice work . one thing is its not allowing to move cursor with left arrow key . Can you please give a solution for it ?

Comment: Here the entered value in the input field is replaced with the dashed(-) expression on each keyup and that is why you are not able to move the cursor. I suppose that is the only possible way. 
However, you can manually place the cursor with mouse-click and edit the value until the maxLength is reached.

Meanwhile, pls keep me posted if you find any alternatives.. :) Happy coding.. B-)

Comment: I filtered the key events for backspace and left arrow so that the above wont fire when we click this 2 keys and it works ..

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Anirudha's answer.

I see other users asking about the cursor and I apologize if I am going off topic here.

For those looking for a phone validation function:

placing @Anirudha's regex in an .on('input') instead of a .keyUp() will solve the cursor issue (so you only update the value when something gets changed). You can also slice and limit it to a 10 digit number.

```
$('.telnumber').on('input', function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join("").slice(0,10); // remove hyphens
  foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}$|.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```