# Auto Reg Ex Phone Number format (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Tags: javascript, regex

I found a pretty old example but it's almost doing exactly what i need to do:
[Auto Dash using Javascript on FOCUS (for a telephone number format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112011/auto-dash-using-javascript-on-focus-for-a-telephone-number-format)

However instead of the current format xxx-xxx-xxxx i'd like to do (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Can someone give me a hand with the script below with this??

```
$('.telnumber').keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value
        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
        .replace(/-*$/g, '');

    console.log("this value", this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
var a = this.value.match(/\d*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1);

this.value  = ['(',a[0],') ',a[1],'-',a[2]].join('');
```

It's not very elegant but hey, elegance is for tailors right?

**Update**

Yea, I got bored and made a one-liner, here:

```
this.value =  '('+this.value
        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1)
        .map((a,i)=>(a+[') ','-',''][i])).join('');
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses, this one worked for me exactly!

Comment: I just realized I'm unable to edit or delete the number after i've typed it in.

Answer (score 0):

The code you'll want to change is `.join('-')`.  That's where you're getting the 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize those 3 regular expressions and then join them separately.