# Css 'const' chars in text input

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to set 'const' chars to text in css or html?
For Example user writes phone number 646830293 and in text (one input) this is 646-830-293 (so every fourth and eighth chars are '-').

Comment: Not in CSS, but yes in Javascript

Comment: You should do it with Javascript as I do not think it can be possible on CSS.

Comment: Use plugins for that: http://www.igorescobar.com/blog/2012/05/06/masks-with-jquery-mask-plugin/

Comment: Could you suggest me how to do it in Jacascript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/juspC/119/ - got this from http://stackoverflow.com/q/19112011/6049581 - might be useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) might the solution for you. It's very simple to use and has very good customization.

From the documentation, you'd write a simple mask with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
  $('.date_time').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
});
```

The whole page has a lot more examples!

Using your [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QfhPzfcV), here's the result:

[image: jQuery Mask working]

Comment: What should I include in html file for use it?

Comment: Since they don't have a CDN (AFAIK), you have to [download](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/archive/v1.14.0.zip) the library then add inside your `<head>` tag with `<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>` ([Very simple explanation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html#external-scripts))

Comment: Well I did it but probably there is another problem. Could you check my basic code please? http://pastebin.com/c2S9mWA6

Comment: You're missing jQuery in your file. Here's a pastebin with it: http://pastebin.com/QfhPzfcV

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do it with pure `CSS` but it is very simple only using `Javascript`.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

var output = text.substring(0, 3) + "-" + text.substring(3, 6) + "-" + text.substring(6);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id="text">646830293</p>
<p id="output"></p>
```